# Way To Append To File While Keeping the File Size Constant

Tags: node.js, filesystems, fs, appendfile

I am looking for a way to write the logs from NodeJS to a file. I am using fs.appendFile option. Is there a way to keep adding to the file by keeping the file size constant--for example, if the file exceeds 5 MB and a new line comes in, delete the oldest line to accommodate the new line--sort of like in a rolling basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to use a library for your logging instead of appendfile. You could use [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) with the [Daily rotate file Transport](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file#usage) where you can cap the filesize at `5MB` or an amount of days or both.

I would suggest zipping up the logs and keeping them for a few days/weeks and setting up a cron job or something to delete the old files.  If you really want to delete all logs, you could delete on rotate

```
transport.on('rotate', function(oldFilename, newFilename) {
    fs.unlinkSync('<log-file-name>')
  });
```

Normally log rotation is handled by the operating system using something like [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)